# Kafka JDBC Sink handle array datatype

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I know that Kafka JDBC Sink Connector have some drawbacks for array datatype. However is it possible to combine the Sink Connector with a simple Kafka Connector which can support array datatype. How can I filter from Kafka configuration and switch them into simple Kafka Connector configuration What does simple Kafka Configuration mean? How can Kafka Connect support array fields

```
name: topic_name
type: array
item: Topic file
```

Is this possible where it will consume to the db as a string not an array

```
"fields":[{
  "name":"item_id",
  "type":{
     "type":"array",
     "items":["null", "string"]
  },
"default":[]
}]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Connect framework itself doesn't expose limitations around types, it's in the source code for the JDBC sink that arrays are rejected.

There's an outstanding PR to support it for Postgres - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/pull/805

Unclear what you mean by "simple", but if you want to use a different connector, then you'd need to install it, and then change the class. For example, maybe the MongoDB sink handles arrays. I know that S3 and HDFS sinks do...

> is it possible to combine the Sink Connector with a simple Kafka Connector

Again, unsure what you mean by this, but connectors generally don't "chain together". While you could use MirrorMaker2 with a transform to effectively do the same work as Kafka Streams, best to use the more appropriate tools for that

> Is this possible where it will consume to the db as a string not an array

Sure, if the message field is actually a string. As suggested, you're going to need to process the message before the sink connector consumes it

Comment: So I tried to use a Debezium sink connector because I read that it supports it, however when I deploy it, i receive a 500 error that needs some connector class to support the Debezium and that JDBC Sink is only option. Is there more configuration, for example in the Dockerfile or yaml file/worker properties of the configuration for it to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893323/debezium-docker-image-fail-to-deploy

Is it possible to extract the array fields and have the other fields to read into the db

Comment: Debezium is a source, not a sink, and your error there is unrelated to connect, but what you've named your docker image

Comment: I see, I named the docker image img.dev/kafka/kafka-sink-connect:{{TAG}}, so do I need more config for the Docker and worker file to support it. I tried to add a HOIST then flatten SMT as the Kafka Documentation https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/hoistfield.html since it says wraps data using a Struct and breaks the fields, I got it to run but no data is coming in with the JDBC Sink. Any suggestions on why? I see INFO Setting offset for partition to topic when I tried HoiseField$Value

Comment: if I change my field from an array type to a struct and I use HOIST and flatten SMT will it read in db

Comment: Based on the documentation, Flatten only applies for Structs and maps, it doesn't traverse arrays. You need to look at logs to see why data isn't written (or what queries try to get ran)

Comment: Since the db column for the array fields is a string, is it possible for Kafka Sink Connect just treat the array fields to be string

Comment: Type coercion isn't possible, no

Comment: So I did the conversion in the producer side, and now topic-flatten depends on topic-name where topic-flatten will do the converting array and struct fields. Is it possible for Kafka to "Sink" the topic-flatten topic to topic-name table